# SONAR - How to exclude packages that is defined under "sonar.test"

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I have a projects in JAVA that I analyze using sonar. Some of the java packages that I have are all under source folder. I also have some test file that I have under a different folders. Now, in Sonar, I organize my projects under a different structure, i.e. for a project "search", I only wants to include "search" package. These exclusion is quite easy to accomplished using sonar.exclusion properties. My question, though, is how about the test? how can I exclude some of the packages? Because from my testing, even though my source and test folder are using the same structure, the test packages are not automatically excluded when I specified "sonar.exclusions".

my folder structure:

```
/src/com/domain/
   -- search/
   -- utils/
   -- pooling/
   -- category/

/test/src/com/domain/
   -- utils/
   -- pooling/
```

Sonar properties:

```
<property name="sonar.sources" value="${path}/src" />
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${path}/test/src" />
<property name="sonar.exclusions" value="com/domain/utils/**/*,com/domain/pooling/**/*,com/domain/category/**/*" />
```

So, I am trying to only include the "search" package. The code above works in a way that it causes SONAR to only analyze my "search" package. This package can be seen in the SONAR "Components" tab. Unfortunately, in addition to the "search" component, I can also see the "util" and "pooling" components. I have done some testing and certain that these two components (utils and pooling) are the result of "sonar.tests" properties. Just a note though, even though "util" and "pooling" shows up in components, SONAR shows zero files under both of them. So going back to my question, is there anyway that I can do to exclude "util" and "pooling" from showing up under "Components"? Maybe using properties (i.e. sonar test exclusions)?

Btw, I am using SONAR 2.11 and is running under Red Hat linux. I'm using SONAR-TASK 1.2.

Any help is welcomed and appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can define exclusions in the Configurations for the project directly in sonar.

[image: exclusions]

Comment: How is this different than if I use "sonar.exclude"? This way seems pretty much the same as what I currently use, except it's using GUI, am I wrong? How can this solve my problem filtering the "test"?
If this is going to work, how can I achieve this using programmatically? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I posted this as an alternative. Basically they both do the same thing. I'm really surprised, that the Tests show up in the components. It shouldn't do that. The doc says that the exclude will be evaluated from the src directory. So I won't assume that tests will be analyzed at all. Do you see any classes in the components?

Comment: I need to clarify this first, so in the components I can see the packages inside "test", so I only see the packages, not "Test" as a component. Inside those packages, there's nothing. Nothing is analyzed. The reason I'm asking is because I find it annoying seeing it in the dashboard, because it gave the impression that those packages are included in the analysis, even though they are not.

Comment: @lwijono did you try value="com/domain/utils,com/domain/pooling,com/domain/category" maybe the problem is, that everything in these folders is ignored, but not the folder itself

Comment: What is that property does? I could not find it in sonar docs under "Advanced parameters". Can you point me out to the docs that uses it? So the way I tested this is by running the script without "sonar.test" and it works perfectly; it only shows the "search" package. However, if I include the "sonar.test" then it will include the "utils" and "pooling" packages. So that's why I conclude that it  is caused by "sonar.test" property.

Comment: sonar.exclusions was defined here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters, sonar.tests is not explicitly mentioned it just says list of test source directories separated by a comma. And I'm quite sure sonar will not analyze those. Perhaps this is some kind of real bug and you should ask the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Since version 3.3, it is also possible to:
>   Exclude tests file from being analyzed: 
>   go to Configuration > Settings > Exclusions and set > the sonar.test.exclusions property

The trick is:

- `sonar.exclusions`: excludes files from sources directory (i.e.`sonar.sources`), it has no effect on tests directory.
- `sonar.test.exclusions`: excludes files from tests directory (i.e.`sonar.tests`), it has no effect on sources directory.

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

And, [Using sonar.test.exclusions with Sonarqube 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176126/using-sonar-test-exclusions-with-sonarqube-6-3)

Comment: the property name is `sonar.test.exclusions` not `sonar.tests.exclusions`