# Sonar, how to exclude binaries

Tags: sonarqube

I am importing my full binaries folder which contains binaries of classes I don't want to analyze, as well as tests that I also want to analyze. Despite Sonar documentation stating that the sonar.properties property supports comma separated values, it is incorrect. If I try to include many folders, separating with a comma, only the first folder path will be included in the analysis.

I know in the Sonar dashboard you can exclude source files, but it does not say anything about  excluding .class files.

Answer (score 1):

> I know in the Sonar dashboard you can exclude source files, but it does not say anything about excluding `.class` files.

Following  "[SONAR - How to exclude packages that is defined under “sonar.test”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8238642/6309)", a directive like:

```
/path/to/class/dir/**/*.class
```

should exclude all `.class` files.
It should be fairly similr to the `sonar.exclusions` [Analysis Parameter](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).